# Find a vector that makes a set of polynomials into a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The problem is the following:

Find one vector $\mathbf{v}$ that makes the following set of polynomials into a basis for the space $P_2$ (vector space of polynomials with degree 2):

{$x, 1+x^2, \mathbf{v}$}

Now I know that a basis of a vector space is a set of vectors that are linearly independent and span said vector space. I tried showing linear independence by taking the determinant of the following matrix of the polynomials:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \newline
1 & 0 & 1 \newline
v_1 & v_2 & v_3
\end{pmatrix} = v_1 - v_3 \neq 0$ for example for $2x^2 + 1$

So can I simply conclude that $v = 2x^2 + 1$ or as a vector $\mathbf{v} = (2, 0, 1)$, or am I going the completely wrong way? Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas/solutions!

Comment: You can conclude that a possible solution is $v = 2x^2 + 1$. There are a great many possible choices for $v$ - in fact, “almost all” choices work.

Comment: You’re not wrong. You chose the third vector as $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ such as the 3 row vectors were linearly independent. You’ve got that any combination other than $v_1=v_3$ is a valid answer then provided an example.

Comment: It is easy enough to see by inspection in this case that linear combinations of $x$ and $1+x^2$ can only produce quadratics for which the $x^2$ and constant terms have the same coefficient. So to get quadratics where those differ, you need a basis vector having different coefficients. A simpler choice than $\mathbf v = 2x^2 + 1$ would be just $\mathbf v = 1$. Then $$ax^2 + bx + c = a[x^2 + 1] + b[x] + (c-a)[1]$$But this approach is only feasible because the example is so simple. For higher dim. vector spaces, the simplest method is matrices + gaussian elimination instead of determinants.